# Parse Text File by String Position

Tags: python, parsing

I have a text file that needs to be split at certain character positions along a line.  Ideally I would like to simply insert a comma at a designated position so that I can then load it into an MS Access table (or similar).  A line form the text looks like so:

"00ZZ101     Bla Bla BlaBlaBlaBla                    022000G0132000R6G00BBDJ1000                           091030820514      BlaBla Bla  1PP"

I need to parse the text from 0:4, and 13:29, and 30:32, and 33:34, and so on......

I need the results to essentially be comma delimited so that I can load them into a table.  So basically take the first four characters and split them, then the 13th through the 29th and split them, and so forth.  The problem in the text file has a carriage return at the end of each line (at the 167th character position).  So I need to split each line into multiple pieces based on some rules that determine what data should be grouped together.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the input and the output? I don't yet see what you want as a result for that example line.

Comment: Are you trying to match a pattern in your input?

Comment: Thanks Simeon.  I modified my post to explain my desired results

Answer (score 6):

From the Python console:

```
>>> s = "00ZZ101 Bla Bla BlaBlaBlaBla 022000G0132000R6G00BBDJ1000 091030820514 BlaBla Bla 1PP"
>>> slices = [(0,4), (13,29), (30,32), (33,34)]
>>> [s[slice(*slc)] for slc in slices]
['00ZZ', 'la BlaBlaBlaBla ', '22', '0']
```

If you are reading strings from each line in an input text file, this is the way to read the file and process each line in turn:

```
with open('xyzzy.txt') as sourcefile:
    for line in sourcefile: 
        # process each line
```

Comment: wow, thanks for the quick repsonse.  i'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: The text file that I'm parsing has carriage returns at the end of each line.  Do I have to build some sort of loop to go through each line?

Comment: Paul I'm having the hardest time processing each line after the for loop.  I tried using the [s[slice(*slc)] for slc in slices] syntax, but it's not working right.  Like I said I'm a "newb" so bare with me.

Comment: Ok, in `[s[slice(*slc)] for slc in slices]` identify for yourself what is `slices`, what is `slc`, what is `slice(*slc)` and what is `s`?  One of these things is the string that you are extracting the different pieces from. Now in the second snippet `with open(etc...`, what is `sourcefile` and what is `line`? Which one of _them_ corresponds to the string you are going to extract the pieces from? Based on what you learn there, you should be able to merge the two snippets.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
s = "00ZZ101 Bla Bla BlaBlaBlaBla 022000G0132000R6G00BBDJ1000 091030820514 BlaBla Bla 1PP"
```

And in python shell

```
>>> s = "00ZZ101 Bla Bla BlaBlaBlaBla 022000G0132000R6G00BBDJ1000 091030820514 BlaBla Bla 1PP"
>>> s[0:4]
'00ZZ'
>>> s[13:29]
'la BlaBlaBlaBla '
>>> s[30:32]
'22'
>>>
```

Comment: wow, thanks for the quick repsonse.  i'll let you know how it goes.